# PHP Yii Framework - Private messaging extension

Tags: php, yii

I encountered really big problems using this extension:
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/private-messaging/

The problem is:

Trying to get property of non-object

in here

```
array(
      'url' => Yii::app()->getModule('message')->inboxUrl,
      'label' => 'Messages' .
      (Yii::app()->getModule('message')->getCountUnreadedMessages(Yii::app()->user->getId()) ?
     ' (' . Yii::app()->getModule('message')->getCountUnreadedMessages(Yii::app()->user->getId()) . ')' : ''),
   'visible' => !Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
```

This line exactly:

```
'url' => Yii::app()->getModule('message')->inboxUrl,
```

So I guess it's problem with getModule('message') being NULL here. But I didn't do anything wrong, I just installed it as in the link I posted. Aby ideas? I tried fixing it for hours... no effect :(

Config related to the module:

```
 'message' => array(
            'userModel' => 'Klient',
            'getNameMethod' => 'getFullName',
            'getSuggestMethod' => 'getSuggest',
        ),
```

There's 'Klient' instead of 'User' because my model of User is called Klient.
Some other infos:
I use XAMPP on Windows.

Comment: When you `var_dump(Yii::app()->getModule('message'));`, what is its type ?

Comment: Show us your config file related with `message` module

Comment: `var_dump(Yii::app()->getModule('message'));` gives NULL, as expected. But I don't know why, it's the same as in the instructions, but doesn't work. It should find the module.. hmm I posted my config related to message.

Answer (score 0):

What is your location of this folder i also. Place it inside `protected/modules/message`

I have also used `yii` `mailbox` in my project you can also look at this 
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/mailbox/

Answer (score -1):

Try changing this below line

`error_reporting(E_ALL);`

into this

`error_reporting(1);`

inside your `ìndex.php` in your root folder(`C:\wamp\www\mysite`). If you don't have that line then add it `error_reporting(1);`

Comment: Why changing error reporting should solve `property of non-object`? Why do you assume OP has WAMP installed? Why you assume OP is using Windows?

Comment: I got the same error on my linux. so i changed into 1 and now it is working for me and also working on windows.

Comment: Hiding errors does not solve your code and it's very bad practice. I assume you also have pile of dust under your bed, because pushing all dusts from ground under your bed makes your room clean.